# Way to keep track of credit card authorization expirations?

Tags: payment-methods, payment, braintree

Is there a a way to keep track of time left on authorizations with your credit card processor? Basically we authorize at the time of purchase and capture when the item ships. The issue is we have 10 days to authorize but because we do samples of our work and also often deal with weekends and holidays, we find those 10 days go by fast and we forget to do captures. I was wondering if anybody made a module which allows me to keep track of all open authorizations, when they will expire, how much time is left,etc. This would be vital to my business.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's a module created specifically to track authorization expirations. Well, I couldn't find one after some extensive Googling. I tried searching for time tracker modules in case you could use something like that instead; however, most of the results I found were for countdown timers to display on your site.

Braintree provides [some info](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/general/statuses#authorization-expired) on how long their authorizations last before being marked as *authorization expired*. You could use this information to build your own module or setup some internal alerts/reminders.

Comment: Thanks. I was able to customize the order details page to put a clock next to the day the order was received, so I can ow look an order and see that 9 days have passed, etc.